# dojo declare with unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am currently trying to expand one of the examples form the dojo website with a declare command, and it has says there is an error on the line "var chart1 = new Chart("simplechart");". I would like to know what is causing this issue, and how it may be fixed. Thank you for your time and help.

```
require(["dojox/charting/Chart",
"dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Lines",
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/domReady!"],
function(Chart, Default, Lines, Declare){

var DefaultGraph = new Declare([Chart, Default, Lines],{
    // Create the chart within it's "holding" node

    var chart1 = new Chart("simplechart");
    chart1.addPlot("default", {type: Lines});
    chart1.addAxis("x");
    chart1.addAxis("y", {vertical: true});
    chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7]);
    chart1.render();

}, "DefaultGraph");
DefaultGraph.startup();
);
});
```

Comment: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" on the first line in the declare code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/stafamus/g2VNQ/) for creating a chart. Just uncomment the lines for declare to create a module.

```
return declare("mychart", null, {
    // var chart1 = new ... etc.
});
```